# Google script to not run a code when the cell is empty

Tags: javascript

Firstly I am trying to learn this, I have no prior experience.

An overview of what I currently have. I want to automate timestamps, and it's all working fine. 
There date entered and last modified. The date entered does not change whenever there is a change made in the data. However, what I want to do now is, when the data is deleted (blank), I want the 'date entered' to be also blank - 'last modified' stills shows a timestamp of any sort of changes made.

Here is the code:

```
   function onEdit(e) {

     addTimestamp(e);

    }

    function addTimestamp(e){
     var startRow = 2;
     var targetColumn = 1;
     var ws = "Sheet1"; 

      var row = e.range.getRow(); 
      var col = e.range.getColumn();

      if (col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) {

        var currentDate = new Date(); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,31).setValue(currentDate);
        if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).getValue() == ""){
          e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).setValue(currentDate);
        if(){  

       } 
      } 

     }
```

Apologies if I made any silly questions.